# Email function in PHP registration script is causing an error

Tags: php, email, email-validation

I am having errors when I try to include an email function into this registration script. The registration script works without the email function, but I want to include this so that if the user wants to change their password, they can do so via email.

The error I get is the following: `

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /storage/ssd4/573/2779573/public_html/pt-5-register.php on line 190`

Line 190 is the fifth from last line on the code block below. Line 190 shows this code; `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);`.

Below is the PHP script which includes the email function:

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php';

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $email = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $email_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";


// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

// Validate username
if(empty(trim($_POST["username"])))
{
$username_err = "Please enter a username.";
} 

else
{

// Prepare a select statement    
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql))
{

// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

// Set parameters
$param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

// Attempt to execute the prepared statement           
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
{

/* store result */
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1)
{
$username_err = "This username is already taken.";
} 

else
{
$username = trim($_POST["username"]);
}

} 

else
{   
echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
}

}

// Close statement
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}


// Validate password
if(empty(trim($_POST['password'])))
{     
$password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
} 

elseif(strlen(trim($_POST['password'])) < 6)
{     
$password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
} 

else
{
$password = trim($_POST['password']);
}


// Validate confirm password
if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"])))
{      
$confirm_password_err = 'Please confirm password.';     
} 

else
{    
$confirm_password = trim($_POST['confirm_password']);     
if($password != $confirm_password)
{      
$confirm_password_err = 'Password did not match.';      
}
}




// Validate email
if(empty(trim($_POST["email"])))
{
$email_err = "Please enter your email.";
} 

else
{

// Prepare a select statement    
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ?";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql))
{

// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_email);

// Set parameters
$param_email = trim($_POST["email"]);

// Attempt to execute the prepared statement           
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
{

/* store result */
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1)
{
$email_err = "This email is already taken.";
} 

else
{
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);
}

} 

else
{   
echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
}

}

// Close statement
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}




// Check input errors before inserting in database
if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && 
empty($confirm_password_err) && empty($email_err))
{

// Prepare an insert statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?)";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql))
{

// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password, 
$param_email);

// Set parameters
$param_username = $username;

$param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a 
password hash

$param_email = $email;

// Attempt to execute the prepared statement
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))

{
// Redirect to login page
header("location: pt-5-login.php");
} 

else
{
echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
}
}

// Close statement
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

} 
  mysqli_close($connect);

}

?>
```

The HTML is not an issue, but if you would like to see the HTML code, please let me know and I will show you the code. The same can be said for the config file `config.php`.

The following is the PHP script of a working registration page, without the email function obviously:

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php';

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"])))
    {
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } 

    else
    {

    // Prepare a select statement    
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql))
        {

        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement           
           if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
           {

            /* store result */
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1)
                {
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } 

                else
                {
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }

            } 

            else
            {   
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

        }


         // Close statement
         mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST['password'])))
    {     
     $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } 

    elseif(strlen(trim($_POST['password'])) < 6)
    {     
     $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } 

    else
    {
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    }

    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"])))
    {      
      $confirm_password_err = 'Please confirm password.';     
    } 

    else
    {    
    $confirm_password = trim($_POST['confirm_password']);     
     if($password != $confirm_password)
     {      
      $confirm_password_err = 'Password did not match.';      
      }
    }

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err))
    {

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql))
        {

        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))

            {
            // Redirect to login page
            header("location: pt-5-login.php");
            } 

            else
            {
             echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($connect);

}

?>
```

Please show me where I am going wrong with introducing the email function. Many thanks

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with your email function. The error occurs because `$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql)` fails and you have `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt)` outside of the if-statement, which means that it will be run even if your statement fails. You should add some error handling: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php

Comment: INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?)", is not correct: 2 questionmarks!

Comment: Magnus Eriksson, I am quite new to PHP. I read the article on MySQLi errors you posted. I am not sure on what kind of error handling that I should include, and I assume that I should include this on line 190?